# Micrsosft outlook window is not acionable when user opens email from IE

Tags: html, email, outlook

Microsoft outlook window is not actionable when user make an email from the IE9.

Steps:

1. Open the Internet explorer (>=9 version) and open any web page suppose www.stackoverflow.com
2. click on 'File' of the IE and select send-->page by email. Then it automatically open an email page in outlook
3. Observe that the page you've opened in IE9 gets pasted in the body of the outlook email and the subject as 'Emailing:*******.htm' is opened
4. click on the outlook window other than this email window and observe that it is not actionable.

how can we make it actionable(it should respond to the other user requirements)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do that - IE uses Simple MAPI do display the message, and Outlook's implementation of Simple MAPI displays the message modally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any quick or easy way to do this, so I think you would have to look at Add-ins for this. I don't know of any myself though for this.

Outlook has behaved like this for years, and it is annoying - same thing happens when you click a mailto: link on a page. Can you get your user(s) to try Chrome instead and perhaps use an extension there for emailing pages?

Might be quicker/easier to deploy a workaround.

Comment: I've to do with the IE itself. No other alternate to follow for my requirement.